# The set of all matrices over $\Bbb F_2$ that are not inverses of themselves

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, involutions

Is there a general rule to identify all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ consisting only of entries $0,1$ such that the matrix has an odd determinant (and hence invertible) and is not the inverse of itself?

I know specific examples of such $A$. Like ones along the diagonal and above the diagonal and zeros below the diagonal is invertible and $A^{-1}\neq A$ but am wondering if we can identify all such $A$?

Comment: Just to confirm: you're working over the finite field of order 2 here, right?

Comment: @user3482749 Yes, that's right.

Comment: Well for starters the order of $GL_n(F_q)$ is $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^i)$, so you know you have $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(2^n-2^i)$ total possible invertible matrices. Next, if you don't care about the matrices being invertible, you have $2$ possibilities for each entry in an $n\times n$ matrix, so you have $2^{n^2}$ possibilities. The difference counts how many are not invertible.

Comment: @TyJensen Thanks, but I am looking for a count of how many are invertible AND such that $A\neq A^{-1}$?. Also, I am looking for a way to find all such $A$?

Comment: Yes, I thought so, I just thought knowing what to except numerically might help. A matrix is invertible if all its column vectors are linearly independent, maybe that could help? Also maybe looking for when $A^2 \neq I$ might be easier than looking for when $A \neq A^{-1}$. That's about all I can help with, good luck!

Comment: @TyJensen No you are right, that did help, I forgot about how to count the total number of possible invertible matrices, True, I am thinking about $A^2\neq I$ now, that might lead me to the answer.